# Using Ipython widgets with Plotly

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly-python, ipywidgets

I am try to use create a dynamic stock information renderer. I had it working with matplotlib, but I wanted to move to Plotly. However, once I switched over to Plotly my chart no longer displays. Jupyter-lab is not outputting any errors for my code.

```
from ipywidgets import VBox, HBox, Text, Button, widgets, Layout
from IPython.display import display
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

class StockGraph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tickers = {}
        self.lines = []
        self.views = {
            "Raw Data": lambda x: x,
            "Rolling Average": lambda x: x.rolling(rolling.value).mean(),
            "Rolling Variance": lambda x: x.rolling(rolling.value).var(),
            "Rolling Standard Deviation": lambda x: x.rolling(rolling.value).var()**0.5,
            "Rolling Coefficient of Variation": lambda x: (x.rolling(rolling.value).var()**0.5) / (x.rolling(rolling.value).mean())
        }


    def plot_data(self, *args):
        if start_date.value.year > 1900 and end_date.value.year > 1900:
            new_df = pd.DataFrame()
            while self.lines:
                item = self.lines.pop()
                item.remove()
            for tick in self.tickers.keys():
                df = self.tickers[tick]
                start = datetime(start_date.value.year, start_date.value.month, start_date.value.day)
                end = datetime(end_date.value.year, end_date.value.month, end_date.value.day)
                selection = df.loc[(df.index >= start) & (df.index <= end)]
                value = self.views[calculation.value](selection[data_type.value])
                new_df[tick] = value
            fig = px.line(new_df, x=new_df.index, y=new_df.columns)
            fig.show()

    def render_stocks(self, *args):
        if stock_text.value != '':
            ticker = yf.download(stock_text.value.upper(), period="max", progress=False)
            if not ticker.empty:
                self.tickers[stock_text.value.upper()] = ticker
                self.plot_data()
        stock_text.value = ''
        boxes = [self.completed_stock(each) for each in self.tickers]
        tickersWidget.children = ([VBox([VBox(boxes), HBox([stock_text, stock_button])])])


    def completed_stock(self, ticker): 
        tickerField = Text(value=ticker,layout=Layout(width='50%',))
        removeButton = Button(description='Remove', button_style='danger',layout=Layout(width='50%',))
        return HBox([tickerField, removeButton])


    def completed_stock(self, ticker):
        def remove_stock(_):
            if tickerField.value in self.tickers.keys():
                self.tickers.pop(tickerField.value)
                self.render_stocks()
            self.plot_data()
                    
        tickerField = Text(value=ticker,layout=Layout(width='50%',))
        removeButton = Button(description='Remove', button_style='danger',layout=Layout(width='50%',))
        removeButton.on_click(remove_stock)
        stock_view = HBox([tickerField, removeButton])
        return stock_view
    
    def finish_matplotlib(self):
        ax.legend()
        title = f"{calculation.value} of {data_type.value} from {start_date.value.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}"
        title += f" to {end_date.value.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}"
        ax.set_title(title)
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale()
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

graph = StockGraph()

# Setting up a basic view with an empty field and a button
stock_text = widgets.Text(value='',layout=Layout(width='50%',))
stock_button = widgets.Button(description='Add',layout=Layout(width='50%',))                                 
stock_button.on_click(graph.render_stocks)
tickersWidget = HBox([stock_text, stock_button])

# Choose data to be shown
calculation = widgets.Dropdown(value="Raw Data", options=graph.views.keys(),layout=Layout(width='auto',))
data_type = widgets.Dropdown(value="Close", options=['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume'],layout=Layout(width='auto',))
calculation.observe(graph.plot_data)
data_type.observe(graph.plot_data)
dropdowns = VBox([calculation, data_type])

#Choose dates to be shown
start_date = widgets.DatePicker(value=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365),disabled=False,layout=Layout(width='auto',))
end_date = widgets.DatePicker(value=datetime.today(),disabled=False,layout=Layout(width='auto',))
start_date.observe(graph.plot_data)
end_date.observe(graph.plot_data)
dates = VBox([start_date, end_date])

#Other Settings for Users
rolling = widgets.Dropdown(options=list(range(2,101)), value=60,description='Rolling:',disabled=False,layout=Layout(width='auto',))
rolling.observe(graph.plot_data)

final_view = VBox([tickersWidget, dropdowns, dates, rolling],layout=Layout(width='20%',))
display(final_view)
```

I would love for some insight on why the chart will not show.

Comment: Please can you construct a more minimal example. Can you see a normal plotly chart in your notebook?

Comment: I copy and pasted a minimal example with iPython widgets and Plotly into my notebooks and it worked fine.

Comment: OK so you need to work up from your minimal example, adding the functionality by steps until you get to where it doesn't work. Then post *that* example. You have a lot of extra code here that isn't the cause of the issue, extra dependencies, yfinance etc when you could build a simple dataframe with pandas for example.